# Writing data to a file as JSON file using fs.appendFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a novice with Node and JS and am trying to achieve a very simple task.

I'm generating new customer data as `surname : customerNumber` e.g. `Johnson: 4784858`

I'd like to write that to a file called custs.json.  So far using the following:

```
function writeCustsToFixtureDataFile(lastName, custNo) {
  fs.appendFileSync(
    `fixtures/customers.json`,
    `${JSON.stringify(custNo)} : ${JSON.stringify(lastName)} \n`
  );
}
```

This yields:

```
"Smith" : "102938" 
"Jones" : "948765" 
"Griffiths" : "829839"
```

When I need:

```
{
"Smith" : "102938", 
"Jones" : "948765",
"Griffiths" : "829839" 
}
```

I know it's staring me in the face, but how do I JSON.stringify the file when first writing to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code stringifies customer number, and last name individually.  To get a comma separated list (surrounded by "{}") you want to create an object, then stringify the entire object, and finally append the stringified version to the file.

For example:

```
const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
JSON.stringify(car);
```